# make FaceTime louder

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, facetime

How do I make the FaceTime.app sound output louder on my MacBook?

It's too quiet for me to hear what the people on the other end are saying. Way quieter relative to every other app I use (YouTube in Safari, Discord calls, Microsoft Teams calls, etc.)

macOS Catalina 10.15, FaceTime 5.0

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with third party apps such as [SoundBooster](https://froyosoft.com/soundbooster.php) from FroYoSoft or [Boom3D](https://www.globaldelight.com/boom/) from GlobalDelight.

They will allow you to control and optionally amplify the audio volume of each app separately.